# ManyToMany relation is not persisted

Tags: php, symfony4

I have `Post` And `PostTag` entities. Only custom users are allowed create `PostTags`. While creating a post user may select post tags.

I have created many to many relationship between Post And PostTag entities using the `make:entity` command.

The problem is that after creating the post and attaching to it the selected tags the relation table **is empty** and nothing is returned by `post.getPostTags()` method.

**PostController** - create method:

```
...
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $post = $form->getData();
    $post->setAuthor($this->getUser());
    $post->setCreatedAt(new DateTime);
    foreach ($form->get('post_tags')->getData() as $postTag) {
         $post->addPostTag($postTag);
    }
    $em->persist($post);
    $em->flush();
...
```

**Post entity**:

```
     /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\PostTag", mappedBy="post", cascade={"persist"})
     */
    private $postTags;



    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->postTags = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection|PostTag[]
     */
    public function getPostTags(): Collection
    {
        return $this->postTags;
    }

    public function addPostTag(PostTag $postTag): self
    {
        if (!$this->postTags->contains($postTag)) {
            $this->postTags[] = $postTag;
            $postTag->addPost($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removePostTag(PostTag $postTag): self
    {
        if ($this->postTags->contains($postTag)) {
            $this->postTags->removeElement($postTag);
            $postTag->removePost($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }
```

**PostTag entity**:

```
     /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Post", inversedBy="postTags", cascade={"persist"})
     */
    private $post;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->post = new ArrayCollection();
    }
    /**
     * @return Collection|Post[]
     */
    public function getPost(): Collection
    {
        return $this->post;
    }

    public function addPost(Post $post): self
    {
        if (!$this->post->contains($post)) {
            $this->post[] = $post;
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removePost(Post $post): self
    {
        if ($this->post->contains($post)) {
            $this->post->removeElement($post);
        }

        return $this;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have set the PostTag entity as the owning side (by virtue of setting `inversedBy` parameter on that entity), so you have to persist the PostTag entity, not the Post entity, to make things stick. You can make a simple modification to your Post entity to make this work:

```
public function addPostTag(PostTag $postTag): self
{
    if (!$this->postTags->contains($postTag)) {
        $this->postTags[] = $postTag;
        $postTag->addPost($this);

        // set the owning side of the relationship
        $postTag->addPost($this);
    }

    return $this;
}
```

Comment: Yes, that was the case. I have already figured it out, but I did it by again creating the ManyToMany relation ship but in reverse and it worked. Your answer seems to me more easy way to make it. Thank you.